# OpenMP: What is the difference between foo() and bar()

Tags: import, openmp

```
void foo(void) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
            {fprintf(stderr, "first part\n"); }
        #pragma omp barrier   
        #pragma omp single
           { fprintf(stderr, "second part\n"); }
    }
}
void bar (void) {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma  omp sections
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "first part\n"); 
             #pragma  omp section
             fprintf(stderr, "second part\n"); 
         }
    }
}
```

Q1-are foo() and bar() equivalent?

Comment: I guess that, since you introduce your question with "Q1", this is from some tutorial or homework.

Comment: yes i had that question as a reserch !!

Answer (score 5):

They are *not* equivalent.

`foo()` will execute the two `fprintf` (parts) sequentially.  `bar()` may execute them in parallel.

For an exhaustive reference you may refer to the [IBM compiler documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cellcomp/v101v121/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp101.cell.doc/compiler_ref/prag_omp_sections.html).

Essentially, in the case of `foo()`, a single worker thread handles `first part`, then completes and resynchronizes with the master thread (the `barrier` is, by the way, implicit at the end of a `single` construct.)  A new worker thread then handles the `second part`, completes, and resynchronizes with the master thread.

In the case of `bar()`, a separate worker thread handles each section (the first section, `first part`, is an implicit section.)  The worker threads complete work in parallel.

> #### #pragma omp parallel
>
> The omp parallel directive explicitly
> instructs the compiler to parallelize
> the chosen block of code. When a
> parallel region is encountered, a
> logical team of threads is formed.
> Each thread in the team executes all
> statements within a parallel region
> except for work-sharing constructs.
> Work within work-sharing constructs is
> distributed among the threads in a
> team.
>
> Loop iterations must be independent
> before the loop can be parallelized.
> An implied barrier exists at the end
> of a parallelized statement block.
>
> Nested parallel regions are always
> serialized.
>
> #### #pragma omp single
>
> The omp single directive identifies a
> section of code that must be run by a
> single available thread.
>
> An implied barrier exists at the end
> of a parallelized statement block
> unless the nowait clause is specified.
>
> #### #pragma omp section, #pragma omp sections
>
> The omp sections directive distributes
> work among threads bound to a defined
> parallel region.
>
> The omp section directive is optional
> for the first program code segment
> inside the omp sections directive.
> Following segments must be preceded by
> an omp section directive. All omp
> section directives must appear within
> the lexical construct of the program
> source code segment associated with
> the omp sections directive.
>
> When program execution reaches a omp
> sections directive, program segments
> defined by the following omp section
> directive are distributed for parallel
> execution among available threads. A
> barrier is implicitly defined at the
> end of the larger program region
> associated with the omp sections
> directive unless the nowait clause is
> specified.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bit of what I remember about OpenMP, with help from this [resource](http://www.ncsa.uiuc.edu/UserInfo/Resources/Software/Intel/Compilers/8.1/f_ug2/par_prg.htm).

- `SECTION` directives "specify parallel execution for arbitrary blocks of sequential code. Each SECTION is executed once by a thread in the team."
- `SINGLE` specifies a block of code "where exactly one thread is allowed to execute the code; threads not chosen to execute this section ignore the code."
- A `BARRIER` directive forces all threads to meet at that point, thus producing a block until all threads have caught up.